# C++ std::function returning const reference

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and there's a lot that I don't understand yet.

Why does the compiler (gcc 9.4.0) accept the following?

```
std::function<const int& ()> f = []() -> int { return 1; };
```

I believe this creates a dangling reference; but how/why does it compile without even a warning? (I have specified `-Wall -Wextra`.)

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) cautions about "when a `std::function`, whose result type is a reference, is initialized from a lambda expression without a trailing-return-type". But I did specify the return type. Furthermore, I can create (what I believe is) the same behaviour without a lambda:

```
int GetSomeValue() { return 1; }
std::function<const int& ()> g = GetSomeValue;
```

Removing `const` from the return type causes a compile error, which is what I expect/want. Why does this make such a significant difference?

Comment: Both lambdas and `std::function` are red herrings.  The problem is having a function that returns a reference, and binding that reference to a dying object.  Can be a temporary like here, can also be a local variable inside the function.  If the lifetime ends before the caller gets to use the object, it's wrong.

Comment: Temporaries bind to const reference, so the conversion is valid, even if it leads to dangling reference :-/

Comment: You are right that it is undefined behavior. If you look on that same site under Notes, the example `std::function<const int&()> F([] { return 42; });` is effectively what you describe and will be an explicit error in C++23. As for why it's not a warning, I can only speculate. However, in general there are some complicated rules (such as binding a temporary to a const-ref extending the lifetime of the temporary) that may make it hard for the compiler to deduce

Comment: `g++ -std=c++20` seems to disallow this.

Answer (score 2):

This is [fixed in C++23](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2255r2.html), where [*`INVOKE<R>`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional) rejects calls for which [`std::reference_converts_from_temporary_v <R, decltype(INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN))>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/reference_converts_from_temporary) is `true`. As of the present date, the only compiler I am aware of that implements this check is g++, version 13.1 and above:

```cpp
static_assert(not std::is_invocable_r_v<int const&, int()>);
```

This means that g++ 13.1 and above will [reject](https://godbolt.org/z/GsMzeK9Ex) your code:

```
error: conversion from '<lambda()>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<const int&()>' requested
    2 | std::function<const int& ()> f = []() -> int { return 1; };
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Note that g++ 13.1 and above will do so even in pre-C++23 mode, since GCC has [chosen](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104477) to apply the change as a DR.

Honorable mention goes to MSVC, which [warns](https://godbolt.org/z/qqPa3cbrc) C4172 "returning address of local variable or temporary".

Answer (score 1):

If you store a function that returns a value in a `std::function` that returns a reference, the `std::function` will return a reference to a temporary.

Lambdas aren't special in this regard, but a lambda without a trailing return type will always return a value (never a reference), so this is an easy mistake to make, and that's why the caution.

Regarding needing the const reference for it to compile, as comments have stated, only const lvalue references can bind to temporaries, so trying to return a non-const lvalue reference to a temporary won't compile.  Returning a const reference to a temporary, however, will compile but won't work.

Comment: I'm curious about a few things here. "If you store a function that returns a value in a std::function that returns a reference": Why is this allowed? // "the std::function will return a reference to a temporary": Are there cases where that's a sensible thing to do? // "only const lvalue references can bind to temporaries": I need to read about what that means.

Comment: It never makes sense to return a dangling reference, but it's syntactically legal.  `int& func() { int x = 0; return x; }` compiles, but it returns a reference to a stack variable that no longer exists.  In this case, returning a non-const lvalue reference compiles because `x` is an lvalue (just one whose lifetime is about to end).   In the case of  `int inner() { return 1; }  int& outer(){ return inner(); }`, it would not compile because `inner()` returns an rvalue, and the `int&` return type cannot bind to an rvalue.  If `inner()` were your lambda, this is your situation.